# Covert mod-rewrite to lighttpd for lessn url shortener

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I am trying to use [lessn](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2009/08/17/less_n), a url shortener by Shaun Inman, on my lighttpd server and he uses a .htaccess file for the redirect.  I am not very good with Mod_Rewrite isn the first place otherwise some simple googling would have sufficed to convert this for lighttpd.  As it is, I do not know what the 2nd and 3rd lines of the Mod_Rewrite are doing, so I cannot convert. I'd appreciate anyone's advice on those so I can have it working as it should. Thank you!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine   on
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
    RewriteRule     (.*) index.php?token=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Haha, I am and will be still be trying to figure this out in the meantime, and I just realized that I don't really understand the 4th line either (at least the (.*) and [QSA,L] parts).

Comment: ok, this page - [packtpub.com/article/migration-from-apache-to-Lighttpd](http://www.packtpub.com/article/migration-from-apache-to-Lighttpd) is helpful, but it seems like the rewrite rule has to be handled by a cgi script?

Comment: The (.*) is a regular expression (regex) to match everything and the QSA stands for "query string append" which is anything after the ? in a URL, the L indicates this is the last line of the rewrite rule that should run if there is a match to the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines instruct Apache's mod_rewrite to NOT apply the rewrite rule to files (f) and directories (d) that physically exist on the file system:

```
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
```

For a long time, lighttpd did not support this behavior out of the box and you had to use mod_magnet with a lua script, like this example:

http://drupal.org/node/43782

However, it looks like there is support now:

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModRewrite#urlrewrite-repeat-if-not-file

So, just use that rewrite construct in your lighttpd.conf, something like:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
  "^/(.*)$" => "/index.php?q=$1"
)
```

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed! In case anyone is searching this later for _lessn_, the above code should be `url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
  "^/(.*)$" => "/index.php?token=$1"
)`

Comment: Also, the working directory for lessn ( http://yourdoma.in/-/ ) needs to have the default page (index.php) work, so you need to make the entire line this: `url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
        "^/-/([^\?]*)(\?(.*))?$" => "/-/$1/index.php?$3",
        "^/(.*)$" => "/index.php?token=$1"
)`